# Styles Format Openxml

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to build a document with Openxml,

when i add a style to the styles.xml  and try to validate it, i get the following error

The element has unexpected child element 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:rFonts'

here is the styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
<w:style w:customStyle="true" w:styleId="33" w:type="paragraph">
<w:name w:val="Heading 1"/>
<w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
<w:next w:val="Normal"/>
<w:rPr>
<w:color w:val="E32020" w:themeColor="light2"/>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri Light"/>
<w:sz w:val="32"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:style>
</w:styles>
```

Can someone help me understand whats wrong with my style.

Comment: Try renaming. "Heading 1" is the name of a **built-in style** - two styles can't have the same name and a built-in style cannot be removed. That, or change the definition of the built-in style to be what you need for "Heading 1".

Comment: I tried renaming the styles,that didn't work, would like to try modifying the built in style, do you know how i can change the built in style using openxml?

Comment: Similar to your other question, with the renamed style version of your code: Can you open the document in Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an error on the part of the Open XML validator, which you can ignore. If you look at the [specification of the w:rPr element](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_rPr-4.html), `w:rFonts` is clearly a permitted child element of `w:rPr`. If you open the document in Word (as hinted by Cindy) and Word does not complain, you are fine.

As Cindy also noted, your style definition has the issue that you are using `Heading 1` as the style name. Since the built-in style's name is `heading 1` (note the lowercase "h"), this would even work on the Open XML level (but you might not see your exact style name in Word, because Word will use "Heading 1" as the display name at least if your display language is English). However, Word would change your `w:styleId` value (which is "33" in your example). The rule is that the `w:styleId` value is a function of the `w:name` value. For example, if your style's `w:name` value is "My Style Name", the corresponding `w:styleId` value should be "MyStyleName". At least this is what Word will use once you save the document in Word.

For built-in styles, the names are localized and do not exactly follow that rule. For example, the built-in "Heading 1" style's `w:name` value is "heading 1" and the `w:styleId` value is "Heading1" (note the uppercase "H") if you have chosen English as the display language. If you have chosen German or French, for example, the `w:styleId` values would be "berschrift1" or "Titre1", respectively. The German `w:styleId` value would actually have to be "Überschrift1" (note the umlaut), but Word simply strips umlaut characters from `w:styleId` values.

In your case, if you stick to "Heading 1" as the style name, Word could not use "Heading1" (in the English version) and would append a character to the `w:styleId` value to be able to differentiate between those styles.

Assuming you have English as your display language, to modify the built-in "Heading 1" style, you will need something like the following, which in this example is simply the standard "Heading 1" style as used by Word in the `Normal.dotx` template.

```xml
  <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Heading1">
    <w:name w:val="heading 1"/>
    <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:next w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:link w:val="Heading1Char"/>
    <w:uiPriority w:val="9"/>
    <w:qFormat/>
    <w:rsid w:val="008A559F"/>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:keepNext/>
      <w:keepLines/>
      <w:spacing w:before="240" w:after="0"/>
      <w:outlineLvl w:val="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="majorEastAsia" w:hAnsiTheme="majorHAnsi" w:cstheme="majorBidi"/>
      <w:color w:val="2F5496" w:themeColor="accent1" w:themeShade="BF"/>
      <w:sz w:val="32"/>
      <w:szCs w:val="32"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:style>
```

Note again that the `w:name` value is "heading 1" with a lowercase "h". Also note the `w:rFonts` element, showing that the validator is wrong.

Comment: You are right, the Heading style changes due to the default heading styles being applied. By altering the names i can add them successfully. Thanks